# Vertically centre text in a div

Tags: css, html, alignment, text-alignment

I am trying to display the text "I’m an iOS Engineer & Web Developer from London, UK" centrally aligned in the `div` with an id of 'london'. However, I am struggling to find a good way to do so. Horizontal alignment was easy as I just had to set the `text-align` property of the 'london' `div`. However, when trying to vertically align, I am unable to set the `width` and `height` properties meaning that I cannot use `margin: 0 auto;` to vertically align the text, as I am using `span` elements.

Please can you tell me the best way to acomplish this?

Here is a JSFiddle with what I have at the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/5aX7p/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <span class="inner">This is vertically centered.</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    display: table;
}
.inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

I altered your fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5aX7p/5/

Note that using CSS tables is better (IMHO) than altering line-height or padding or margin or whatever, because it always vertically centers the inner span, even if it wraps onto multiple lines.  With other solutions you have to tweak the values for the line-height or padding or margin if the size of your content changes.

Comment: It's actually supposed to be `vertical-align: middle`, not `vertical-align: center`. ;)

Comment: Oops, thanks!  Edited to take that into account.  I got the fiddle right, does that count? :)

Answer (score 0):

If your `#london` division is always going to be 200px high, you could just change `height: 200px` to `line-height: 200px` and it will vertically center the text in the line.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/5BDcr/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that center aligns (taken from your fiddle):

```
<div id="london">
            <span class="light" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 1.2;">I’m an 
                <span class="heavy">iOS Engineer &amp; Web Developer</span>
                <span class="light"> from London, UK</span>
            </span>
</div>
```

with this added to the CSS for #london:

```
line-height: 200px;
```